# Using thymeleaf in my servlet, html template file not found

Tags: java, servlets, thymeleaf

I am trying to use thymeleaf to read an html template, remplace a variable in it and then send it as an email. However I am stuck at the part of reading the html template file.

This is the error i get:

```
The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u></p><p><b>exception</b> <pre>org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template &quot;invitationemail&quot;, template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
    org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:247)
    org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1192)
    org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1148)
    org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1095)
    org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1008)
    org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:982)
    yesterscape.ses.SESManagement.sendInvitationEmail(SESManagement.java:69)
    yesterscape.users.InviteUserServlet.doPost(InviteUserServlet.java:68)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

So I am assumig it is because I am not properly setting my invitationemail.html file.

This is the code to read the email and change the value:

```
ClassLoaderTemplateResolver resolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
resolver.setSuffix(".html");
TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(resolver);
final Context context = new Context(Locale.US);
context.setVariable("name", nameFrom);
final String htmlVer = templateEngine.process("invitationemail", context);
```

As you can see, I am setting the suffix as .html and in the name of the file to process i am just typing "invitationemail". But still it cannot be found.

In what folder of my servlet architecture should I include the invitationemail.html file? I thought it should be in the WEB-INF folder, and this is where it currently is but I still have no luck.

Thanks in advice for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: Where exactly is your `invitationemail.html` in folder structure?

Comment: In the project structure (I use eclipse) there is a folder called WebContent, i have a copy of the invitationemail.html here. Also inside this folder there is another folder called WEB-INF and i also have a copy inside that one. Perhaps I am missing something in the configuraition of the resolver or the template engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem fixed. When using the ClassLoaderTemplateResolver (which is the resolver needed for email content) the html files should be placed in the following directory:

> WEB-INF/classes

Answer based on this post: http://forum.thymeleaf.org/springmail-sample-td3945553.html

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `ClassLoaderTemplateResolver` use another `ITemplateResolver` implementation as follows

```
ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/template/");
resolver.setSuffix(".html");
resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
// ... etc
```

And put you email template into `/WEB-INF/template` folder..

Comment: Hey, i tried that but now i get this error. The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.</u></p><p><b>exception</b> <pre>org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Resource resolution by ServletContext with org.thymeleaf.resourceresolver.ServletContextResourceResolver can only be performed when context implements org.thymeleaf.context.IWebContext [current context: org.thymeleaf.context.Context]

Comment: Ok it seems that i fixed the issue, i think its necessary to use the class resolver, but then i found a post saying i should add it in the "classes" folder. Now I am just having parsing issues.